# Why $2^{3^n}=-1 \mod 3^{n+1}?$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Why $2^{3^n}=-1 \mod 3^{n+1}?$

By using the Euler totient function $\varphi$   I have got that
$$
2^{\varphi(3^{n+1})}=2^{3^{n+1}-3^n}=2^{2 \cdot  3^n}=1 \mod 3^{n+1}.
$$
How  to prove now  that the square  root is equal  to $-1?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$(2^{3^n}+1)(2^{3^n}-1) = 0 \mod{3^{n+1}}$$

then remark that $2^{3^n }- 1 = (3-1)^{3^n} - 1 = (-1)^{3^n} - 1 = -2 = 1 \mod{3}$

so $$2^{3^n}+1 = 0 \mod{3^{n+1}}$$

Comment: but $-2 \neq 1 \mod 3^{n+1}$ for $n>1.$

Comment: @Leox We see there is no $3$ in the prime factorization of $2^{3^n}-1$, so all the $n+1$ 3's must be in the prime factorization of $2^{3^n} + 1$

Comment: oh yes,  if no $3$  then no $3^{n+1}$. Thank you!

Comment: @Leox yeah you get it! You are welcome!

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut it's explained by OP in the question. If $a^2 = 1 \mod{b}$, then $(a+1)(a-1) = 0 \mod{b}$

Answer (score 3):

Use induction. You know 
$$2^{3^{n-1}} \equiv -1 \mod 3^n,$$
so
$$2^{3^n} \equiv (-1)^3 = -1 \mod 3^n.$$
You already know that the answer is $\pm 1 \mod 3^{n+1},$ so this is enough to finish the problem!